# Bokeh Zoom Out in the main figure

Tags: javascript, zooming, bokeh, yaxis

I am trying to plot a line graph on Bokeh and i am using 2nd y axis to the right side as well. For this reason i put y_axis_location to None. But when i am trying to change the start and the end option from Range1 does it only to the yaxis not in my main figure. The problem is that i want my application to plot as initial graph this that can be displayed after i zoom out as the 2nd picture above (after zoom out) but what i get is the 1st picture instead.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuAM7.png]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By the way i found what cause this error, it has to do with y_range_name which need to take the name of the y_range that you named at the starting point.